# Proguard + zxing, My APK doesn't shrink

Tags: android, proguard, zxing

Hi I'm building an android app that uses zxing library for QR Scanning only.

I'm using [zxing'S proguard file](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/proguard-android-optimize.txt?r=2382) file to shrink and optimize the APK, without success.
My APK always ends up with 133 M of size.

Proguard outputs several warnings stating that some class references are missing (some of them are from rt.jar). I've get rid 
of them with: -ignorewarnings

(Maybe this is the problem the APK isn't shrinking)

How can I make the APK to shrink?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are referencing the correct proguard file in your `project.properties` file using the `progaurd.congif=` property.

Comment: I've checked it and it's correctly referenced. What else can it be?

Comment: Are you doing a release build?  How are you building your project: Eclipse, ant, ...?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing a release build with Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm... it should be working. Make sure you don't have a `#` in front of the `proguard.config` property line.  You can also try using the default proguard optimize file/line: `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt`.  Then if there are project specific proguard settings, add them to your project's `proguard-project.txt` file.

Comment: I don't hava a # in front of the proguard.config property, and I've already tried ussing proguards default optimize file (proguard-android-optimize.txt) with the same result: 133M.

Comment: Is your build generating a `usage.txt` file and if so, is there stuff in it?

Comment: Chris, thanks for your help. I have a usage.txt file with about 6000 lines in it, starting with:


android.UnusedStub
android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl
android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanMr2
android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl

Comment: Then it sounds like it is removing unused code from your project.  Do you have a lot of resource files, like png's? Unfortunately, I don't think I can help you any further though.

Comment: We have a normal set of resource files (drawable etc.).
Chris thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Actually, I think I see the problem now based on your answer. The library is keeping all of their files (see the 3 lines under `#ADDED`). You can try changing the 3 `-keep ...` to `keepnames ...`. Doing this can result in issues though if some of the classes are used in xml files but not referenced or used in java files.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing something big here then, because the entire library is nowhere near 133MB. In fact, it is 0.5MB: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.zxing%7Ccore%7C3.1.0%7Cjar

The Proguard file you reference is actually the one Android creates, with a minor change to what optimizations are allowed. It's standard.

Are you somehow packaging *all of the test images* into your APK? That's the only way I can imagine making such a huge artifact. But that is a huge error of course.

Answer (score -1):

We ended up dumping zxing and using a library that only has zxing qr code scanning functionality.

https://github.com/barmstrong/bitcoin-android

Hope this helps someone else.
Regards